# How implement SAS percentile statement into R?

Tags: r, sas, statistics, quantile, percentile

I have such SAS statement:

```
proc univariate data = df noprint;
class &var1. &var2.;
var &var3.;
output out = STAT PCTLPTS = 2 5 98 99 95 PCTLPRE = P;
```

I have output from `SAS proc` like this:

[image]

**How can I get the same result in R?** (with 5 P-columns and values ​​for each row)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `quantile()` function. https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/quantile.html

There is an underlying distribution quantile calculation `type` based on the `SAS` method.

> Type 3 - SAS definition: nearest even order statistic. γ = 0 if g = 0 and j is even, and 1 otherwise.

Use the function like this:

```
quantile(iris$Sepal.Length, probs = c(.02, .05, .98, .99, .95), type=3)
```

> ```
>  2%  5% 98% 99% 95% 
> 4.4 4.6 7.7 7.7 7.2
> ```

You can use various methods, such as `sapply()` to execute `quantile()` on multiple variables. ex.

```
 t(sapply(iris[1:4], quantile, probs = c(.02, .05, .98, .99, .95), type=3))
```

> ```
>               2%  5% 98% 99% 95%
> Sepal.Length 4.4 4.6 7.7 7.7 7.2
> Sepal.Width  2.2 2.3 4.0 4.1 3.8
> Petal.Length 1.2 1.3 6.6 6.7 6.1
> Petal.Width  0.1 0.2 2.4 2.5 2.3
> ```